# du /home | sort -nr +0 -1 | head –10

Tags: sort, du

I am a little confused with this command. Can someone please explain what the output of this command is? I see it in my terminal, but I do not understand what it is showing me.

Comment: Read `man du sort head bash`, and all will be explained.

Comment: What did you hope to learn by using that particular incantation?

Comment: @waltinator I don't think `man sort` covers the "traditional" `+A -B` key selection syntax, does it? They'd need to scour the `info` page for that... certainly the first time I've come across it